# Build errors in unity for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, google-community-connector

I'm facing critical errors while attempting to build my 3D game in Unity. As a newcomer to Unity (using version 2021.3.20f1), I find myself struggling to resolve these issues.

[image]

The errors appear during the build process for Android.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your error and relevant parts of your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be a Firebase error. Either change the version or delete the Library folder and re-run Unity. Remember to back up the Library before deleting it.
check this [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/getting-backend-produced-unparsable-log-entry-after-upgrading.1288355/)
It will be help you!

Comment: @ewokx there is no code error and i do not understand where is the error in my code. The errors do not point towards any specific code, so I do not understand what should i provide that's why I attached the snapshot so that you guys might help me out with something.